# How to get maximum column values across a row in Teradata sql?

Tags: teradata

I have a table named cnst_chrctrstc_abc with 10 columns (equ_gender1 - bb_population_flag) each row which contain numeric values (count) . 
I want to get maximum 5 values out of each row across those 10 numeric columns.

The query I have looks something like the following ..

```
SEL 
FROM 
(
SEL 
SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(act.equ_gender1,'') = COALESCE(inact.equ_gender1,'') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) AS equ_gender1_chg_cnt,
SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(act.exp_ex_bmyr1,'') = COALESCE(inact.exp_ex_bmyr1,'') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) AS exp_ex_bmyr1_chg_cnt,
SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(act.equ_age1,'') = COALESCE(inact.equ_age1,'') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) AS equ_age1_chg_cnt,
SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(act.maritalstatus1,'') = COALESCE(inact.maritalstatus1,'') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) AS maritalstatus1_chg_cnt,
SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(act.person_type1,'') = COALESCE(inact.person_type1,'') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) AS person_type1_chg_cnt,
SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(act.homeowner,'') = COALESCE(inact.homeowner,'') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) AS homeowner_chg_cnt,
SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(act.dwelling_size,'') = COALESCE(inact.dwelling_size,'') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) AS dwelling_size_chg_cnt,
SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(act.lengthofresidence,'') = COALESCE(inact.lengthofresidence,'') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) AS lengthofresidence_chg_cnt,
SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(act.childrenage0_18,'') = COALESCE(inact.childrenage0_18,'') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) AS childrenage0_18_chg_cnt,
SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(act.bb_population_flag,'') = COALESCE(inact.bb_population_flag,'') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) AS bb_population_flag


FROM
(SEL * FROM arc_mdm_Tbls.cnst_chrctrstc_abc WHERE load_id=1024 AND cnst_chrctrstc_end_dt='9999-12-31' (DATE))act
LEFT JOIN
(SEL * FROM arc_mdm_Tbls.cnst_chrctrstc_abc WHERE load_id=1024 AND cnst_chrctrstc_end_dt<'9999-12-31' (DATE) 
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cnst_mstr_id ORDER BY cnst_chrctrstc_strt_ts DESC)=1
)inact
ON act.cnst_mstr_id = inact.cnst_mstr_id
)X
```

I know SEL GREATEST would produce the maximum value out of each row . But I want 5 top values and assign a rank to them.

Something like for some row first five columns may hold the top 5 values and for some last five i.e. homeowner to bb_population_flag may hold the top 5 values.

so if the columns and values from cnst_chrctrstc_abc look something like the following

```
cdi_batch_id | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i |j
1024         |116|105|102|100|117|119|108|104|101|121
```

so the select query should return me columns j,f,e,a,g having the top 5 values.
And then I would assign a rank to them accordingly .

Should it be done using **unpivot** or something ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, lots of questions: #1: you're comparing the current version of a row with it's previous version (this can probably be rewritten using an OLAP function). #2: your current query returns a single row, so you probably want individual rows instead of the `SUM`. #3: Your result should return 5 rows and each of the columns should have the five top values? Or five rows per column (only this column or the others, too)? What if there are duplicate values?

Comment: Yes . Number 2 asssumption is correct. Actually I want to select the top five values something like SEL GREATEST(
-----
) and then assign rank to those column values and insert to some other table .

Comment: Can you add example data plus the expected result?

Comment: Please have  a look. Thanks.

Comment: Final question: What's your Teradata release?

Comment: TD14 is my current teradata release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to unpivot your result.

Before TD14.10 you will need a list of those column names, either as a table

```
create table ColumnList (col varchar(128));
Insert into ColumnList('equ_gender1'       );
Insert into ColumnList('exp_ex_bmyr1'      );
Insert into ColumnList('equ_age1'          );
Insert into ColumnList('maritalstatus1'    );
Insert into ColumnList('person_type1'      );
Insert into ColumnList('homeowner'         );
Insert into ColumnList('dwelling_size'     );
Insert into ColumnList('lengthofresidence' );
Insert into ColumnList('childrenage0_18'   );
Insert into ColumnList('bb_population_flag');
```

or on-thy-fly using a bulky

```
with ColumnList as 
 (
   select * from (select 'equ_gender1'        as Col) as dt union all
   select * from (select 'exp_ex_bmyr1'       as Col) as dt union all
   select * from (select 'equ_age1'           as Col) as dt union all
   select * from (select 'maritalstatus1'     as Col) as dt union all
   select * from (select 'person_type1'       as Col) as dt union all
   select * from (select 'homeowner'          as Col) as dt union all
   select * from (select 'dwelling_size'      as Col) as dt union all
   select * from (select 'lengthofresidence'  as Col) as dt union all
   select * from (select 'childrenage0_18'    as Col) as dt union all
   select * from (select 'bb_population_flag' as Col) as dt
 )
```

Then you CROSS JOIN to unpivot:

```
select
   col,
   case col 
      when 'equ_gender1'        then equ_gender1       
      when 'exp_ex_bmyr1'       then exp_ex_bmyr1      
      when 'equ_age1'           then equ_age1          
      when 'maritalstatus1'     then maritalstatus1    
      when 'person_type1'       then person_type1      
      when 'homeowner'          then homeowner         
      when 'dwelling_size'      then dwelling_size     
      when 'lengthofresidence'  then lengthofresidence 
      when 'childrenage0_18'    then childrenage0_18   
      when 'bb_population_flag' then bb_population_flag
   end as Counts,
   rank() over (order by Counts desc) as rnk
FROM
 (
   your current select
 ) as dt
cross join ColumnList
qualify rnk <= 5
```

In TD14.10 you could utilize the `TD_UNPIVOT` function:

```
SELECT Col, rank() over (order by Counts desc) as rnk 
from TD_UNPIVOT(
        ON (
             your current select
           )
        USING
           VALUE_COLUMNS('Counts')
           UNPIVOT_COLUMN('Col')
           COLUMN_LIST('equ_gender1'
                      ,'exp_ex_bmyr1'
                      ,'equ_age1'          
                      ,'maritalstatus1'
                      ,'person_type1'
                      ,'homeowner'
                      ,'dwelling_size'
                      ,'lengthofresidence'
                      ,'childrenage0_18'
                      ,'bb_population_flag')

        ) dt
qualify rnk <= 5;
```

Edit:

Additionally you might replace your LEFT JOIN with a single OLAP-function. Depending on the number of rows per `cnst_mstr_id` this might be more efficient as you need a `ROW_NUMBER` anyway:

```
SEL 
SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(equ_gender1,'') = COALESCE(last_equ_gender1,'') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) AS equ_gender1_chg_cnt,
...
FROM
 ( SELECT 
      min(equ_gender1) OVER (PARTITION BY cnst_mstr_id ORDER BY cnst_chrctrstc_strt_ts DESC rows between 1 following and 1 following) as equ_gender1,
      ...
   FROM arc_mdm_Tbls.cnst_chrctrstc_abc 
   WHERE load_id=1024
   qualify cnst_chrctrstc_end_dt= date '9999-12-31'
 )act
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I did not understand the cross join part

Comment: It should give me a Cartesian product right ? How would it help me transpose the table.

Comment: Exact, it will return 10 rows and the case unpivots each column in one of those rows, that's the manual way to unpivot. In your new question you try the same using multiple `UNION ALL`, same result, but much more overhead to create it...